# FP3 Integration help

Tags: integration

$$I_{n}=\int x^n(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} dx$$
Show that 
$$(n+2)I_{n}=(n-1)I_{n-2}-x^{n-1}(1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

So far I have done this:

$$\int x^{n-1}(x)(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} dx$$
$$u=x^{n-1}$$
$$u'=(n-1)x^{n-2}$$
$$v'=x(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$v=\frac{-1}{3}(1-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}$$
$$I_{n}=\frac{-x^{n-1}}{3}(1-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}+(\frac{n-1}{3})\int x^{n-2}(1-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}dx$$
$$3I_{n}=-x^{n-1}(1-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}+(n-1)\int x^{n-2}(1-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}dx$$

What do I do next?

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: The hint will be: $(1-x^2)^{3/2} = (1-x^2)(1-x^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Let $x=\sin t$. You'll have $\sqrt{1-\sin^2t}=d(\sin t)=\cos t$. Then use the fact $\cos^2t=1-\sin^2t$, and employ [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).